# SSL: What is relation between bio and socket regarding blocking/non-blocking mode?

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl

To set bio non-blocking, do I also need to set the underlying socket non-blocking?

```
   int flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL);
   fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);  // <== is it necessary?
   BIO* bio = BIO_new_socket(sock, BIO_NOCLOSE);
   BIO_set_nbio(bio, 1);
```

In general, what happens if bio is non-blocking/blocking but the underlying socket is blocking/non-blocking? I search the man page but no detail description.

Comment: You should be using [`BIO_set_nbio()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man3/BIO_set_nbio.html)

Comment: And `BIO_new_connect()` instead of setting up a socket manually if possible.